# Splitting a string into 2 strings on character postion

Tags: c#, string, server, client, readline

I'm currently developing a client and server for storing and searching a user ID (e.g 542351) and location (e.g "is in the library")

This is the code I'm currently using to separate the received client arguments (User Id "location").

```
static void doRequest (NetworkStream socketStream)
{
    string Protocol = "whois";
    Dictionary<string, string> userLocationData = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    try
    {
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(socketStream);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(socketStream);

        //sw.WriteLine(args[0]);
        //sw.Flush();
        //Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());

        String Line = sr.ReadLine().Trim();
        Console.WriteLine("Request Received: " + Line);
        string[] sections = Line.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, 2);

        string username = sections[0];
        string location = sections[1];
        string result;

        if (location == null)
        {
            if (userLocationData.ContainsKey(username))
            {
               Console.WriteLine("Requested user location found."); //Server side only
               userLocationData.TryGetValue(username, out result);
               sw.WriteLine(result);
               sw.Flush();

            }
            else
            {
                        Console.WriteLine("Requested user location NOT found."); //Server side only
                        sw.WriteLine("ERROR: no entries found");
                        sw.Flush();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            userLocationData.Add(sections[0], sections[1]);

            if (userLocationData.ContainsKey(username))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("User location has been updated.");
                sw.WriteLine("OK");
                sw.Flush();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error, could not add user to database.");
            }
        }
    }

    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Something went wrong");
    }
}
```

Basically, my server can handle when 2 arguments are sent- as it breaks these into 2 strings using the `Line.Split(new char[] {' '}, 2);`

The problem is when a user only sends 1 argument from the client e.g. just the user ID (6 digit number), the server doesn't catch it and throws the catch something went wrong.

I assume this is because when the server only receives the user ID, 1 argument, it can't split the string in 2 since there is no space or anything to fill the second sections[1] string.

Essentially I just need to be able to read the string and separate it into 2 strings if it's more than just the user ID.

e.g 55432 "is in the library" - would need to be 2 strings

e.g 55432 - would only be 1 string.

Comment: I am confident the error is coming from the line `string location = sections[1];` if the split only returns ONE (1) item. The `string.Split` command (`string[] sections = Line.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, 2);`) is using a `count` parameter of 2, which defines “the maximum number of substrings to return.” The code makes the assumption that `sections[1]` will always exist, which is NOT true.

Comment: If the split only returns ONE (1) item, which it “would” if the string had no spaces, then `section[1]` will NOT exist. Therefore, the line `string location = sections[1];` is going to crash and burn. The `catch` portion is catching this, however, the code simply spits out a vague non-descript “Something went wrong” message. I suggest actually catching the exception (`catch (Exception ex)`) and display what the error message is with  `Console.WriteLine("Error: “ + ex.Message)`. I am confident you will get the index out of range error.

Comment: The “2” in the split simply says if there are many returned strings, then you only want the first 2. Given the string “123456 123456 123456” the posted split would return `sections[0] = 123456` and `sections[1] = 123456 123456`. If the split is less than 2 items then it will only return 1 item not two. I am guessing you should be checking the array size before you try and access an item in it.